# Set option bypassDocumentValidation for Laravel MongoDB (jenssegers/mongodb)

Tags: laravel, mongodb, validation, eloquent, jenssegers-mongodb

I try to update my Eloquent model while bypassing the validation (because some items break their schema).

As I understand the mongodb package, it should be possible to pass an option
['bypassDocumentValidation' => true]

I tried to set this option both in the DB config

```
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
             ...
            'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'options'  => ['bypassDocumentValidation' => true]
        ],
```

as well as using the update

```
Brand::find($brand->_id)->update([$data, ['bypassDocumentValidation' => true]);
or 
$brand->save(['bypassDocumentValidation' => true]);
```

Every time, I still get the validation error ("Document failed validation").

How can I pass the option to MongoDB?

Comment: What version of `jenssegers/mongodb` are you using?

Comment: using jenssegers/mongodb 3.9 (and laravel 9.12)

Comment: Try making an entry like `'driver_options' => ['bypassDocumentValidation' => true]` in the DB config,

Comment: @OluwafemiSule no, that didn't work

Comment: Hmm, that's really weird since it's being passed down when the [connection is created](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/v3.9.0/src/Connection.php#L175) and also when the [query is performed](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/v3.9.0/src/Query/Builder.php#L857). My guess is that the driver may not be respecting this configuration at the end.